# How come I can select a column from a different table than the referenced table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm learning the basics of SQL. The two tables I made are bands and albums

```
CREATE DATABASE record_company;
USE record_company;
CREATE TABLE bands(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE albums (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    releaseyr INT,
    band_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES bands(id)
);
```

I do not understand how I just selected the count of band_id from the table, bands, when band_id is from the table, albums.

```
SELECT bands.name, COUNT(band_id) as numofalbums FROM bands
LEFT JOIN albums ON bands.id = albums.band_id
GROUP BY bands.id;
```

[Here's the result, showing band_id as numofalbums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qT49.png)

Comment: You can always `SELECT` from all table columns that present in any `JOIN` operation. You can try something like `SELECT * ` to show all table columns, `SELECT bands.* ` to show all columns from `bands` table only or `SELECT albums.* ` to show all columns from table `albums` only.

Comment: It knows that `band_id` is from `albums` because none of the other tables involved in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses have a column named `band_id`.

Comment: @/FanoFN I see, it makes sense that for join table to select columns from albums